# Is Iddah required if the couple has been seperate for a long time before divorce?

Tags: talaq, iddah

Me and my children's father lives in different country for almost a year and half and he divorced me.

Do I have (العده) which is three months because we didn't meet for two years now?

Comment: when exactly did you get divorced?

Comment: @Amin probably she was divorced and immediately wrote here